# Can we edit minified javascript files directly in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, .net, c#-4.0, minifiedjs

I have two js files in my project. Customvalidation.js and CustomValidation.min.js. I completed my project and during release I had a change in js . So , here Can I directly go ahead and edit minified file or CustomValidation.js first I have to do ? I know it is recommended to do in both js so that future development will be easy.

But my question Is it possible to edit directly min.js ? If possible , then when it will be compiled again ? In my front-end code I am referring min.js only.

Comment: First of all a Script language is not compiled it is interpreted by runtime, so no worries there for you. Of course you can edit it, but the min.js is a bit confusing with variable names etc. So why not generating the min.js new and just replace the old one?

Comment: @Torben : Ya ok,, Cool,, Thanks,, Got It. Main concern was will it be an issue in runtime if there is any discrepancy between min.js and js file ? In my code (actually in my mvc view) am referring min.js file only.

Comment: No issues the min.js and the "original" .js can have differences. It is only important which one you are reffering to, because the Content of this will be interpreted.